# IF-THEN-ELSE: Create / Truncate Table - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to create a backup table without having to re-create it every single time. If the table already exists in the next run then it should simply truncate the table.

But it doesn't seem to be working. It says `backup_reportsettings` is already in the database. Can anyone assist me with this?

```
--Only re-create table if table does not exist otherwise truncate the existing table.   
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Misc].sys.tables where name= 'dbo.backup_reportsettings')
    CREATE TABLE [MISC].dbo.backup_reportsettings 
    (
        [datestamp] [datetime] NULL,
        [reportsettingid] [char](8) NOT NULL,
        [description] [char](30) NOT NULL,
        [formname] [char](30) NOT NULL,
        [usersid] [char](8) NOT NULL,
        [settings] [text] NOT NULL,
        [notes] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [userdefault] [char](1) NOT NULL
    )
ELSE 
    TRUNCATE TABLE [Misc].dbo.backup_reportsettings;
```

What am I doing wrong? Note: this is done within a transaction.

Comment: You truncate the table but didn't delete the table, so it is telling you that you have it already in your database

Comment: `truncate` wipes all the data from the table, it doesn't drop it

Comment: I do not want to delete the table. This will be part of the script so essentially I do not want to re-create the table on every run. So I just want to create it the first time and in the next run if the table is there then I just want to truncate it before I insert the records.

Comment: @Lamak I know truncate simply removes all the rows and does not delete the table schema.

Answer (score 4):

Object names in `sys.tables` don't have the schema as part of the name. Remove the table schema when verifying whether the table exists:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Misc].sys.tables where name= 'backup_reportsettings')
```

Answer (score 3):

Despite the use of `IF`, SQL Server needs to Parse/Compile all the statements in your script, so when it sees a `CREATE TABLE` statement it will give you a compilation error if the table already exists, even though the `IF` would prevent that code from being executed when that is the case.

The way to get around this is to put your `CREATE TABLE` statement in dynamic SQL, which will not be parsed/compiled before execution.